# Identifying keyboards that provide/support Boot Protocol descriptors

Tags: usb, hid

I have an app that relies on HID USB devices [Boot Protocol](https://deskthority.net/wiki/USB).
Is there a way I can, beforehand, know if a keyboard supports Boot Protocol or not ? Is this something based on a consistent criterion, like VID/PID, or a random manufacturer decision ?